# How to show directory name only, instead of whole path in os.walk

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, operating-system, os.walk

So if I want to print only the directory name instead of whole base path, is there any tricks to achieve it :)

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/lungsang/Desktop/levelpack-UI/content/A0/1 docx-raw"):
    print(root)
```

Here I get the result :

```
/home/ubuntu/levelpack-UI/content/A0/1 docx-raw
```

My desired result : only the directory name only.

```
1 docx-raw
```

Comment: Try `os.path.basename(root)`

Answer (score 0):

Standard os.path functionality:

```
print(os.path.split(root)[1])
```

Seems too trivial for the stackoverflow I guess. Anyway...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is `print(root.split("/")[-1])`

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me. thnx !

```
import os

out = os.path.basename("/home/ubuntu/levelpack-UI/content/A0/1 docx-raw")
print(out)
```